# expected value of conditional uniform distribution

Tags: expected-value

Suppose $U$ is the uniform distribution from $0$ to $1$. I wish to compute $E(U|U<1/2)$. Intuition suggests that this should just be $\frac{1}{4}$. However, when I try and compute it explicitly, I get $\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}} y dy = \frac{1}{8}.$ This makes me think there is something fundamentally wrong with how I compute this expectation. What's the proper way to do this?

Comment: $E[U\mid U<1/2]=E[U I(U<1/2)]/P(U<1/2)$, where $I()$ is an indicator variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you condition on $U < 1/2$, your conditional distribution is no longer equal to $1$; the integral $\int_0^{1/2}1dy = 1/2$, so the constant of integration must equal $2$, otherwise the conditional distribution won't integrate to $1$.  More explicitly,

$$f(u|u < 1/2) = {f(u) \over \int_0^{1/2}f(u)du} = {1 \over 1/2} = 2$$

Multiplying your result of $1/8$ by $2$ gives you the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

[jbowman](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/7555/jbowman)'s conditional density is correct. I wanted to add the CDF derivation of the conditional density.

Starting from the cumulative distribution function
$$
P(U < u \mid u < 1/2) = \frac{P(U< u, U<1/2)}{P(u< 1/2)} = \frac{P(U < \min(u,1/2))}{P(U < 1/2)} = 2P(U \leq  \min(u,1/2))=\begin{cases}2u, & \text{for }0 < u < 1/2\\ 1, & \text{for } 1/2 \leq u < 1 \end{cases}.
$$
Thus, the conditional density of $U \mid \{ U <1/2\}$ is the derivative of the conditional density:
$$
f(u\mid u < 1/2) = \begin{cases}2, &\text{for }0 < u < 1/2\\ 0, & \text{for }1/2 \leq u < 1. \end{cases}
$$
And this is why you need to multiply your answer by 2.